# Perl Excel::Writer::XLSX

Tags: perl, excel-writer-xlsx

I'm trying to create an excel file using perl scripting.
  I followed the tutorial and write the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX::Utility;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );    # Step 1
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('cc');                   # Step 2
$worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Hi Excel!' );
```

But I got the following error :

```
Global symbol "$worksheet" requires explicit package name at test_excel.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$worksheet" requires explicit package name at test_excel.pl line 11.
```

Comment: When you say tutorial, do you mean the synopsis in the CPAN documentation?

Comment: Add `my ` to the left of the first occurence of `$worksheet`

Comment: This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that wasn't declared via "our" or "use vars", localized via "my()", or wasn't fully qualified. please check url https://perlmaven.com/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the `$worksheet` variable, like this

```
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('cc');                   # Step 2
```